# How to open extension in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I have installed two extensions in Visual Studio 2010.

- Regex Tester
- Regular Expression Tester Extension

Both extensions installed successfully. I restarted Visual studio. But I don't see them. I couldn't find the way to use them or open them.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both extensions have a guide on their page.

Regex Tester: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/16b9d664-d88c-460e-84a5-700ab40ba452

Regular Expression Tester Extension: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bf883ae3-188b-43bc-bd29-6235c4195d1f